# How to upgrade the MySQL version to the latest version in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, version, upgrade

I'm working with WordPress to create a website and it appears to be a problem, therefore I need to upgrade the MySQL version. I have already installed MySQL (8.0.15) to my computer, but when I go into phpMyAdmin it still appears the older version (5.1.55). How can I upgrade the version in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall phpMyadmin,download latest phpMyadmin ang install it. Be sure to back up your files that is important.